# Postgresql 9.5 won't start and doesn't give any indication to why not

Tags: mac, postgresql

I have postgresql 9.5 running for a DaVinci Resolve shared server. (Postgresql is installed via the DaVinci installer)
Today the power went out and killed the Mac Mini that the server is running on. 
After rebooting postgres stopped working and I can't figure out why.

I try to launch the server:

```
LFTapeRobot:data postgres$/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/ -l /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/server.log start

server starting
```

And get the message that the server is starting.

But when I run a status nothing has happened:

```
LFTapeRobot:data postgres$ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/ -l /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/server.log status
pg_ctl: no server running
```

This is the output to the log

```
2019-06-12 13:48:40 CEST LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process

2019-06-12 13:48:40 CEST HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".
```

I have no backups of the database so I don't want to just reinstall.
And I can't run pg_dump because I can't get the server to run.

I tried moving the data folder to another computer with 9.5 installed but the same issue happens there.

There is no postmaster.pid file to delete.

Is there maybe a way to dump the database without launching the server?

Comment: Have you looked for error logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill When I check the server.log it only outputs the following. I can't find the pg_log directory. Are there any other error logs?: 2019-06-12 13:48:40 CEST LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2019-06-12 13:48:40 CEST HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".

Comment: So have you looked in `pg_log`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was an idiot. I couldn't find pg_log and the I ran a find command but I was looking for files and not directories. The files in pg_log told me that line 85 of pg_hba.conf was making problems.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.